# How to identify similar sublists in a list and visualize the clusters?

Tags: list-manipulation, visualization

Consider a list (`list`) as

```
list = {{50, 124, 53, 25, 100, 28, 5, 52, 3, 4}, {1, 51, 31, 27, 25, 28, 2, 
  50, 4, 26}, {26, 23, 75, 1, 24, 50, 2, 25, 4, 3}, {29, 28, 27, 23, 
  26, 7, 25, 4, 3, 1}, {51, 75, 23, 53, 27, 22, 5, 1, 50, 4}, {75, 25,
   27, 4, 28, 5, 51, 50, 3, 1}, {25, 76, 22, 23, 26, 5, 4, 50, 27, 
  2}, {52, 7, 23, 49, 4, 1, 24, 3, 50, 27}, {3, 25, 22, 73, 27, 74, 2,
   49, 21, 4}, {71, 79, 29, 8, 154, 75, 46, 125, 100, 54}, {48, 27, 
  50, 52, 26, 25, 4, 2, 6, 3}, {5, 76, 28, 49, 52, 26, 4, 25, 3, 
  50}, {76, 30, 75, 74, 100, 49, 1, 4, 3, 25}, {27, 53, 4, 54, 1, 5, 
  3, 26, 25, 2}, {75, 1, 50, 5, 26, 4, 2, 51, 25, 3}, {49, 23, 52, 50,
   28, 4, 6, 1, 2, 3}, {100, 28, 26, 53, 52, 48, 50, 4, 2, 3}, {78, 
  77, 1, 50, 98, 25, 125, 48, 4, 73}, {62, 56, 75, 8, 101, 154, 125, 
  46, 100, 54}, {125, 153, 56, 8, 53, 154, 99, 46, 100, 54}, {101, 
  124, 21, 2, 100, 50, 54, 3, 24, 25}, {22, 74, 28, 73, 21, 4, 99, 26,
   1, 51}, {28, 73, 100, 3, 49, 50, 23, 25, 1, 2}, {23, 22, 5, 4, 52, 
  3, 100, 27, 2, 1}, {7, 49, 77, 78, 125, 22, 4, 3, 25, 52}, {25, 98, 
  2, 125, 73, 50, 4, 48, 23, 52}, {77, 123, 100, 125, 102, 25, 75, 48,
   4, 73}, {105, 8, 106, 154, 99, 179, 46, 125, 100, 54}, {52, 146, 
  53, 8, 56, 50, 154, 46, 54, 100}, {1, 55, 26, 200, 125, 100, 50, 54,
   75, 25}, {146, 47, 28, 103, 49, 27, 52, 2, 50, 73}, {2, 103, 100, 
  1, 99, 29, 76, 25, 50, 26}, {100, 50, 125, 74, 104, 49, 1, 75, 25, 
  77}, {74, 50, 26, 20, 28, 49, 52, 77, 1, 25}, {2, 25, 49, 125, 5, 4,
   75, 48, 52, 23}, {98, 75, 102, 48, 77, 25, 4, 125, 5, 73}, {150, 
  58, 8, 53, 46, 55, 154, 125, 100, 54}, {55, 146, 53, 101, 52, 46, 8,
   154, 54, 100}, {71, 151, 75, 51, 99, 24, 53, 100, 125, 25}, {25, 
  50, 21, 52, 47, 28, 96, 77, 72, 75}, {50, 27, 73, 23, 49, 24, 100, 
  2, 25, 51}, {99, 124, 25, 24, 97, 27, 51, 72, 100, 50}, {150, 99, 
  24, 4, 52, 74, 102, 26, 27, 25}, {1, 75, 102, 2, 73, 125, 4, 52, 23,
   48}, {75, 72, 3, 77, 125, 98, 25, 48, 4, 73}, {53, 104, 102, 46, 8,
   75, 154, 125, 100, 54}, {146, 55, 50, 8, 75, 53, 154, 46, 54, 
  100}, {29, 50, 124, 1, 125, 49, 150, 54, 100, 25}, {123, 1, 49, 51, 
  21, 151, 53, 48, 26, 100}, {50, 148, 49, 75, 73, 28, 23, 1, 26, 
  25}, {29, 26, 125, 75, 77, 49, 25, 51, 1, 50}, {101, 125, 4, 53, 77,
   25, 52, 51, 49, 75}, {73, 75, 102, 24, 50, 4, 48, 52, 23, 2}, {100,
   3, 98, 102, 125, 5, 77, 4, 48, 73}, {29, 8, 46, 179, 79, 75, 53, 
  125, 100, 54}, {125, 51, 146, 105, 55, 8, 46, 154, 54, 100}, {48, 
  101, 24, 52, 150, 125, 25, 26, 100, 54}, {50, 100, 22, 2, 51, 49, 
  24, 75, 28, 1}, {101, 22, 47, 102, 71, 28, 27, 50, 51, 1}, {23, 26, 
  51, 27, 28, 48, 49, 2, 1, 50}, {29, 50, 1, 125, 27, 52, 77, 4, 53, 
  28}, {127, 3, 2, 73, 50, 52, 4, 5, 23, 48}, {102, 100, 98, 77, 5, 
  52, 125, 4, 48, 73}, {8, 50, 150, 75, 79, 25, 46, 125, 100, 
  54}, {52, 22, 28, 3, 99, 27, 53, 100, 25, 54}, {100, 125, 72, 275, 
  150, 50, 25, 175, 22, 28}, {26, 200, 97, 125, 6, 31, 47, 22, 50, 
  28}, {47, 32, 4, 25, 31, 6, 3, 1, 22, 28}, {2, 47, 75, 1, 200, 25, 
  6, 53, 22, 28}, {53, 3, 26, 30, 2, 47, 1, 6, 22, 28}, {47, 2, 23, 
  50, 24, 52, 28, 73, 22, 4}, {23, 25, 1, 4, 5, 77, 75, 125, 48, 
  73}, {51, 2, 3, 30, 53, 1, 54, 28, 27, 125}, {50, 29, 23, 30, 24, 
  22, 2, 26, 27, 28}, {4, 150, 22, 50, 24, 23, 26, 175, 27, 28}, {25, 
  24, 29, 47, 22, 125, 3, 26, 27, 28}, {29, 30, 1, 31, 24, 22, 26, 2, 
  28, 27}, {25, 200, 52, 125, 29, 24, 26, 27, 75, 28}, {33, 3, 2, 23, 
  29, 31, 24, 26, 27, 28}, {22, 200, 31, 75, 29, 125, 2, 26, 28, 
  27}, {18, 125, 75, 47, 25, 53, 52, 1, 73, 4}};
```

Each sublist in `list` has `10` elements. I need to cluster the sublists based on the similarity between them and visualize the clusters. For example, if I set the similarity threshold to be `5` i.e. two sublists will belong to the same cluster if they have minimum `5` common elements, I can have a sample cluster as highlighted in the image below:

[image]

One approach can be to compare each sublist with the other and find the similarity. But this approach is very tedious.

Is there any smarter way to this?

Answer (score 2):

If we define a test function that counts the similar elements

```
similarElements[a_, b_] := 
 Length[a] + Length[b] - Length[DeleteDuplicates[Join[a, b]]]
```

then the clustering is just a matter of doing

```
clusters = Gather[list, similarElements[#1, #2] >= 5 &]
```

To display the clusters together, you can use a combination of `Grid` and `Multicolumn`:

```
Style[Multicolumn[
  Framed@Grid[#, Alignment -> Right, ItemSize -> {1.8, 1}] & /@ 
   clusters, 3], 8]
```

[image: clustering 1]

---

I did not really like ordering by cluster length much though and I thought we could do something better.

For starters, let's sort the clusters by decreasing length and mix then taking one from the beginning and one from the end

```
mid = Ceiling[Length[clusters]/2];
clustersSorted = Reverse@SortBy[clusters, Length];
newclusters = 
  Riffle[Take[clustersSorted, mid], 
   Reverse@Drop[Reverse@SortBy[clustersSorted, Length], mid]];
```

This is the length of the re-sorted clusters:

```
Length /@ newclusters

(* {21, 1, 14, 1, 12, 1, 11, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2} *)
```

Now we can fill the columns by assigning each successive cluster to the column with the least total elements

```
columns = {{}, {}, {}};
Scan[AppendTo[
    columns[[First[
       OrderingBy[columns, Length[Flatten[#, 1]] &, 1]]]], #] &, 
  newclusters];
```

This is the result

```
Style[Row[
  Map[Column[#, BaselinePosition -> Top] &, 
   Map[Framed@Grid[#, Alignment -> Right, ItemSize -> {1.8, 1}] &, 
    columns, {2}]], Spacer[2]], 8]
```

[image: clustering 2]

Better, but still not perfect. The issue here is that the gap between the grids takes up space that we are not counting. Let's add it!

```
columns = {{}, {}, {}};
Scan[AppendTo[
    columns[[First[
       OrderingBy[columns, Length[Flatten[#, 1]] + Length[#] - 1 &, 
        1]]]], #] &, newclusters];
```

And now it's what I wanted

[image: clustering 3]

Answer (score 2):

One possible reading of the requirement

> *if I set the similarity threshold to be 5 (...). two sublists will belong to the same cluster if they have minimum 5 common elements*

is as follows:

```
ClearAll[clusterF]
clusterF[a : ("Index" | "List" | "Grid") : "Grid"] := Module[{lst = #, t = #2, clstr}, 
  clstr = First @ ConnectedComponents @ RelationGraph[
    UnsameQ[##] && Length[Intersection[lst[[#]], lst[[#2]]]] >= t &, Range[Length @ lst]];
  Switch[a, "Index", clstr, "List", lst[[clstr]], _, 
    Grid[lst[[Join[clstr, Complement[Range[Length@lst], clstr]]]], 
      Frame -> {None, None, {{{1, Length[clstr]}, {1, -1}} -> True}}, 
      FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Green]]]] &;
```

**Examples:**

There is a single cluster containing all elements if the threshold `t` is less than 6:

```
TableForm[Transpose[{#, Length[clusterF["Index"][list, #]]} & /@ Range[10]],
 TableHeadings -> {{"threshold", "cluster size"}, None}]
```

[image]

```
clusterF[][list, 6]
```

[image]

```
clusterF[][list, 8]
```

[image]

**Note:** You can use the test function `Length[Intersection[##]] >= 5 &` as the second argument of `Gather` to get the result in @Batracos's answer.

```
 Gather[list, Length[Intersection[##]] >= 5 &] == 
   Gather[list, similarElements[#1, #2] >= 5 &]
```

> True

However, (if the above interpretation of OP's requirement is correct), this result does not satisfy the requirement that *two sublists belong to the same cluster if they have minimum 5 common elements*. For example, `Gather[list, similarElements[#1, #2] >= 5 &]` gives 15 groups with lengths

```
Length /@ (clusters = Gather[list, similarElements[#1, #2] >= 5 &])
```

> {14, 21, 4, 2, 12, 11, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4}

If we check, for example, the intersection of the first element in the third group (`clusters[[3,1]]` with some elements of the first group (`clusters[[1, {2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13}]]`), we see that `clusters[[3,1]]` have 5 or more common elements with each of the elements `clusters[[1, {2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13}]]`, so it must belong to the same cluster per OP's requirement:

```
Length[Intersection[#, clusters[[3, 1]]]] & /@ 
 clusters[[1, {2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13}]]
```

> {5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 6, 5, 5}